# Using git filter-branch to remove commits by their commit message

Tags: git

**Simple Version:**

If I have a branch "foo-555", with a bunch of commits with messages like:

- foo 555: blah
- foo 123: blah blah
- foo 555: blah blah blah
- foo 321: blahblah

and I want to remove all the commits that don't start with "foo 555:", is there any way to do that using git filter-branch (or any other tool for that matter)?

**Original Version (More Detailed):**

In our repository we have a convention where every commit message starts with a certain pattern:

> Redmine #555: SOME_MESSAGE

We also do a bit of rebasing to bring in the potential release branch's changes to a specific issue's branch.  In other words, I might have branch "foo-555", but before I merge it in to branch "pre-release" I need to get any commits that pre-release has that foo-555 doesn't (so that foo-555 can fast-forward merge in to pre-release).

However, because pre-release sometimes changes, we sometimes wind up with situations where you bring in a commit from pre-release, but then that commit later gets removed from pre-release.  It's easy to identify commits that came from pre-release, because the number from their commit message won't match the branch number; for instance, if I see "Redmine #123: ..." in my foo-555 branch, I know that its not a commit from my branch.

So now the question: I'd like to remove all of the commits that "don't belong" to a branch; in other words, any commit that:

- Is in my foo-555 branch, but not in the pre-release branch (pre-release..foo-555)
- Has a commit message that doesn't start with "Redmine #555"

but of course "555" will vary from branch to branch.  Is there any way to use filter-branch (or any other tool) to accomplish this?  Currently the only way I can see to do it is to do go an interactive rebase ("git rebase -i") and manually remove all the "bad" commits.

Comment: Can you not cherry pick the commits you want into the relevant branch?

Comment: We *can*, but let's say I've got 10 555 commits and 10 other commits; I'd have to reset and then do 10 cherry picks (vs. one filter-branch command ... if such a thing is possible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a script to remove lines with `Redmine #555`:

```
#!/bin/sh

mv $1 $1.$$
grep -v 'Redmine #555' < $1.$$ > $1
rm -f $1.$$
```

Of course you can do that however you want (eg `echo` a script of commands to `ed`).

Then launch your rebase with `EDITOR` set to your script:

```
EDITOR=/path/to/script git rebase -i REVISION
```

Of course it still won't be guaranteed to complete -- there may be errors during the rebase caused by leaving out revisions.  You can still fix them and `git rebase --continue` manually.

Comment: This seems like it would work, but ... isn't there any way to just use Git (with no shell scripts) and make the process automated via a "git filter-branch --commit-filter"?

Comment: The help for `--commit-filter` specifically mentions that `skip_commit` leaves out the commit but **not the changes** and says to use `git-rebase` instead.  `filter-branch` considers your revisions as a sequence of states and allows you to permute each commit, but the changes to not propagate to the children.  `rebase` considers your revisions as a stack of patches and any modification midstream *does* propagate to future revisions.  But that can cause failures which is why it can't be fully automatic.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a fast solution that uses `filter-branch` instead of rebasing. There's no interactivity or needing to resolve conflicts.

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    if [ `git rev-list --all --grep "<log-pattern>" | grep -c "$GIT_COMMIT"` -gt 0 ]
    then
        skip_commit "$@";
    else
        git commit-tree "$@";
    fi'  HEAD
```

You'll probably want to then clean up with:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now
git gc --prune=now
```

Comment: For large repositories with a lot of commits, this can take awhile (e.g., several seconds per commit filter on FreeBSD `-CURRENT`, which has hundreds of thousands of commits). A much quicker alternative for the `git rev-list --all [...]` condition is `git show $GIT_COMMIT | grep -c "<log-pattern>"`.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the stated problem. `skip_commit` in `git filter-branch` actually *squashes* commits away, it doesn't remove their changes. To remove them, you need to use `git rebase -i` instead of `git filter-branch`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Gingi answer but simplified if statement

```bash
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
if [[ $(git show -s --format=%B "$GIT_COMMIT") == "fix" ]]
then
    skip_commit "$@";
else
    git commit-tree "$@";
fi'  master
```

Note that after rewriting history you should delete all local and remote tags, otherwise you'll have gangling branches